Salesforce Customer Chat refresh extraPrechatFormDetails field on click of a button
How to refresh the extraPrechatFormDetails details once the chat bot is loaded but before opening the chat window? I want to refresh the details on click of a button before the chat window opens.
Reference
Tried resetting these details on click of a button but it doesn't yield required result
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails=[{....}]

